# UMBRACO - Adding Google Analytics e-commerce code to Umbraco transaction confirmation

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, umbraco

From what I understand, to track successful e-commerce transactions using Analytics, you need to insert the tracking code into a 'thank you for your order' type confirmation page/template.

I'm pretty new to UMBRACO CMS and can't seem to find this confirmation page anywhere. There's just a template for a re-direct to SagePay which is the payment gateway. Also, the site doesn't seem to be using any kind of e-commerce 'package'.

Anybody have an idea where I need to go or what I need to do to successfully implement the GA e-commerce tracking to Umbraco?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions.

When a user has completed an order on your site, what would be the url where he gets the order confirmation displayed?

A common way of using Umbraco is to dynamically change the template of a page, by adding it to the url, so that might be what is going on here. An Example.

The content tree would look like this:
Content
- Home
- - News
- - Cart

Now the cart page would have a url of /cart.aspx as default. But you could access the same page, with a "confirmation" template by using a url like /cart/confirmation.aspx. in this case, there would be no "confirmation" content page, but there would be a "confirmation.master" template in your "settings" section in the Umbraco backend. And that would probably be the place to insert your google tracking code.